# 3D Floating Text in Libgdx Android

Tags: text, properties, libgdx, splash-screen, floating

I am about to finish a libgdx project. But I'm stucked at somewhere about floating text.

In my project, there's a splash screen first, after that in the second screen I have a floating text that floats from "-y", to top of the screen. Here's the thing: 
How can I make this text looks like star wars episode stories? I mean, text should be float vertical + horizontal on both sides + and look like it goes to "-z" ?

I thought about to add video but after my research, I realized that I can not do that in libgdx projects, but I don't know, can I?

I hope I explained my problem clearly. This is not a "must do" thing for my project, but without this effect that screen is kinda meaningless. I'd really appreciated if you guys help me.

Comment: Use a perspective camera for rendering the text. So after you draw everything else, you switch the SpriteBatch projection matrix to the one from your perspective camera. You'll have to align it suitably in relation to your text. You can figure that out by doing the geometry on paper, or it might be easier to lay something out in Blender to figure out good coordinates.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like what I need, thank you very much. Now it's time to fight for making text floating to the right direction. Maybe I should try my Text as a Texture, I don't know. Thank you very much again.

Comment: I do have real problems with that camera... You can call me as a Rookie-which I am- but I really need some help. I don't know how to use the camera with the floating text. I found ways to use it with objects like cubes but Floating Text is something unique to find its examples on WEB. I know I'm asking too much, but could you be more specific on Floating Text + Pers. Camera Usage please?

Comment: SpriteBatch draws stuff on the XY plane in 3D space. So if you put your camera at some position  away from Z=0 and point it at the point on that plane where you are drawing your text, you will see it in 3D. As an example, you can try drawing a Sprite at (-0.5,-0.5) with size (1,1). Put your perspective camera at position (0,-2,5) and call cam.lookAt(0f,0f,0f). You might need to set cam.near to a small decimal value like 0.001f.